# flask how to keep database queries references up to date

Tags: flask

I am creating a flask app with two panels one for the admin and the other is for users. In the app scheme I have a utilities file where I keep most of the redundant variables besides other functions, (by redundant i mean i use it in many different parts of the application)

**utilities.py**

```
# ...
opening_hour = db_session.query(Table.column).one()[0]  # 10:00 AM
# ...
```

The `Table.column` or let's say the `opening_hour` variable's value above is entered to the database by the admin though his/her web panel. This value limits the users from accessing certain functionalities of the application before the specified hour.

The problem is:

If the admin changes that value through his/her web panel, let's say to `11:00 AM`. the changes is not being shown directly in the users panel."even though it was entered to the database!".

If I want the new `opening_hour`'s value to take control. I have to manually shutdown the app and restart it "sometimes even this doesn't work"

I have tried adding `gc.collect()`...did nothing. There must be a way around this other than shutting and restarting the app manually. first, I doubt the admin will be able to do that. second, even if he/she can, that would be really frustrating.

If someone can relate to this please explain why is this occurring and how to get around it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you define this value during import time?

Comment: yes I guess.. I am working on a solution right now using `importlib.reload(app.utilities)` if it works properly I will answer my question. Thank you @NilsWerner for your consideration, I almost gave up on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add advanced logic to a simple variable: You want to query the DB only once, and periodically force the variable to update by re-loading the module. That's not how modules and the import mechanism is supposed to be used.

If you want to access a possibly changing value from the database, you have to read it over and over again.

The solution is to, instead of a variable, **define a function `opening_hours`** that executes the DB query every time you check the value

```
def opening_hours():
    return (
        db_session.query(Table.column).one()[0],  # 10:00 AM
        db_session.query(Table.column).one()[1]   # 5:00 PM
    )
```

Now you may not want to have to query the Database every time you check the value, but maybe cache it for a few minutes. The easiest would be to use [`cachetools`](http://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for that:

```
import cachetools

cache = cachetools.TTLCache(maxsize=10, ttl=60) # Cache for 60 seconds

@cachetools.cached(cache)
def opening_hours():
    return (
        db_session.query(Table.column).one()[0],  # 10:00 AM
        db_session.query(Table.column).one()[1]   # 5:00 PM
    )
```

Also, since you are using Flask, you can create a route decorator that controls access to your views depending on the view of the day

```
from datetime import datetime, time
from functools import wraps
from flask import g, request, render_template

def only_within_office_hours(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time, stop_time = opening_hour()
        if start_time <= datetime.now().time() <= stop_time:
            return render_template('office_hours_error.html')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

that you can use like

```
@app.route('/secret_page')
@login_required
@only_within_office_hours
def secret_page():
    pass
```

Comment: MIND BLOWING!, really love how you made this into a decorator!! all i think about is `if` statements :)).it is as you suggested **You should not try and build business logic that has to leverage tricks like reloading modules**. Thanks again :)