# using Flask import app.module with importlib.reload(app.module)

Tags: python

In my Flask app I have this import statement:

```
from app.my_module import *
```

and in some parts I need to keep the module up to date so I did the following:

```
importlib.reload(app.my_module)
```

the above line causes the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'utilities'

how can i reload `app.my_module` without having it raising that error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Flask debug mode should do the auto reloading for you...

Comment: it is not :-(, you can check the detailed issue in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089149/flask-how-to-keep-database-queries-references-up-to-date

Comment: Do you ever use `flask.utilities` while only importing `flask`?

Comment: I am sorry i don't get your question, In fact the actual module is app.utilities .@MadPhysicist

Comment: I can do the following `import app.my_module ... importlib.reload(app.my_module) ` and access the functions and variable as such `app.my_module.my_variable`. but that is somehow annoying/a lot of redundant in code/doesn't feel right . so maybe there is another way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try and build business logic that has to leverage tricks like reloading modules because of a module variable that might change. If you have models that may yield different values at different times of the day, you should make that behaviour explicit, e.g. by using object instances, functions, or data collections like a dict.